# Screen with different options for autorotate

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I have a view with a collection of images. If the image is clicked then I show it full screen on same screen. When the phone is rotated, I want it to autorotate only if the image is full screen, otherwise no. I have `isZoomedIn` that is true when a image is full screen else false.

I have implemented the method `shouldAutorotate`. If it is zoomed-in it returns Yes otherwise No but it doesn't work even if `isZoomedIn` is set corectly.

Answer (score 1):

I created a demo having a button to pop-up a new view on same screen similar to your image selection on clicking.

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender  //Called when button tapped to pop-up a new view.
{
  flag = YES;  //Flag check for rotating new view ,i.e., YES.

  newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, self.view.frame.size.width-10, self.view.frame.size.height-10)];
  [newView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

  closeNewViewBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 100, 50)];
  [closeNewViewBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(removeView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  [closeNewViewBtn setTitle:@"Remove View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [closeNewViewBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

  [newView addSubview:closeNewViewBtn];

  [self.view addSubview:newView];
}

-(void)removeView  //Called to remove view or in your case change it for removing the image or what ever you doing.
{
  flag = NO;
  [newView removeFromSuperview];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate  //Rotation check
{
  if(flag)
    return YES;  //Will rotate when new view is present.
  else
    return NO;   //Will not rotate when new view is not present.
}
```

This will get you required needs.

Comment: Hey, I came across a issue. When you rotate newView to landscape and close it in landscape only then the parent view would be in landscape only but as you rotate it will come back to portrait and won't rotate further. So I tried to find solution for same but actually you can't force parent view to rotate to portrait. Therefore, better option for you will be to use a new view controller to show your image in full screen and then when moving back to root view controller force it to portrait if image view controller was in landscape. Hope helpful to you !